# How to fill a circle with rotated stripes in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How can I fill a normal circle with rotated stripes in Adobe Illustrator?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I wouldn't say that was an exact duplicate. Similar, but not exact.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the black lines to be even (ie. not taper at the ends), another option is to used a stroked dash. Here's what I did:

1. Make 3 circles
2. Subtract circle 3 from circle 1
3. Add a dashed stroke to circle 2 the same width as the distance between circles 1-3.

[image: Dashed circle image]

Comment: This is the way to do it. Super old-school technique, but perfect for the job. Adjustable too!

Answer (score 1):

- You make a star shape with many faces like this.
- You add 2 circles, position them where you need them, centered with the star. Use the Pathfinder tool to crop out the bits you dont need.

[image]